# How to use Nakai-Moishezon criterion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, blowup

> ***Theorem (Nakai- Moishezon)***:  A Cartier divisor $D$ on proper scheme $X$ is ample if and only if, for every integral subscheme $Y$ of $X$, one has $D^{\text{dim}(Y)}. Y > 0$
>
> ***Defintion***: Let $X$ be a complete scheme. A divisor $D$ on $X$ is said to be **very ample** if there exsts a closed immersion $X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}_{k}^{r} = \mathbb{P}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{X}(D) \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}}(1)|_{X}$. We apply the same terminology to the associated line bundle $L = \mathcal{O}_{X}(D)$.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective scheme and $Z$ a smooth projective subscheme of $X$ and $\pi: \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ be the blow up of $X$ along of $Z$ with exeptional divisor $E$.

Let $H$ be an ample divisor on $X$.

**How to use Nakai-Moishezon's theorem to show that the divisor $\pi^{*}mH - E$ is very ample on $\widetilde{X}$ for all integers $m$ sufficiently large** ?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you do it for the case of smooth projective surface and $f$ a blow-up at a point?

Comment: Dear random. Yes ! I already checked this for the case you mentioned. Now, I'm trying to make the case where $Z = C $ is a smooth curve. Any help is very welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: I learned to use the criterion in the case suggested by you by reading the article: Very Ample Line Bundles on Blow up- Projective Varieties- Edoardo Ballico. In points, the problem is solved. I want to see now how the criterion works for a subvariety of $Z$ with dimension $n \geq 1$. Thank you.

Comment: More specifically. I want to understand the case where $Y = \mathbb{P}^{3}$ and $Z = C$ is a smooth  algebraic curve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link : https://mathoverflow.net/a/164144/58056. Using this it can be shown that $D^3 > 0$ and possibly other conditions in the criterion of ampleness. Although I haven't checked that if that works.

Comment: Ok, Random 123. I'll look at this. Thanks for the sugestion.

Comment: Dear, Random. I followed your suggestion.  Actually, the answer is a bit confusing. For me, the morphisms p and i are, respectively, the blow up in Y and the inclusion of the exceptional divisor. However, the first equality: $\widetilde{H}^{h-i}E^i = p^*H_Y^{n-i}\cdot i^*E^{i-1} = H_Y^{n-i}\cdot p_*i^*E^{i-1}$, do not make that clear.

Comment: For example, if $i$ is  the inclusion morphism, what would be $i^{*}E^{i-1}$?. Thank you so much.

Comment: The notations you are using are correct. The notation $i^*E^{i-1}$ has been used to indicate the class $[E].E^{i-1}$. This is also called the Gysin map. You find it in Fulton's intersection theory Chapter 2 section 2.6.

Comment: In particular the following identities that have been proven there are useful : $\widetilde{H}^3 = 1$, $\widetilde{H}^2\cdot E = 0$, $\widetilde{H}\cdot E^2 = -d$, and $E^3 = 2-2g-4d$.

Comment: Ok, Random 123. I'm going to study this chapter of Fulton's book. Any questions, I will write again here in the forum. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Here's an MO post describing a solution that doesn't use N-M in case that helps you or someone else out: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212031/pull-back-of-an-ample-line-bundle-under-a-blow-up/212045#212045

Comment: @KReiser. I will read this answer. Thank you very much for your attention to the question.